# Jasper Report issue Report design not valid & java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Gradle

Tags: gradle, jasper-reports, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

i am working on multimodule project and generating the jasper reports using gradle anttask. i am using the Gradle ant task

my project structure is:-

```
`RootProject -A
 module-B ---> some classes are using from here during jasper report generation.
 module-C ---> added ant task in build.gradle and .jrxml files are in this module.
 `
```

.jrxml files are in module-C and when i am generating the reports its searching
for some classes that are present in module-B.
as i have defined classpath under anttask in module-c - 
`classpath(path: sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)` 
 it wont able to get the classess from module-B.  Please advice how to get the classes that are required while executing the jaspertask

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'war'

 group = 'org.C'
 version = '1.0.0'

description = 'C Module'
sourceSets {

main {
    java { srcDir 'src' }
    resources { srcDir 'resources' }
}
test {
    java { 
            srcDir 'test' 

        }
    }
}

    sourceCompatibility = 1.6
    targetCompatibility = 1.6

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
  //added other repositories as per the requirement

}
 configurations {
jasperreports {
    transitive = true
}

}
 gradle.projectsEvaluated {
processResources.dependsOn(compileJasperReports)
}
dependencies {
jasperreports 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:5.6.0',
        'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.6'
}

 task compileJasperReports {
def jasperSourceDir = file('src/main/jasper')
    ant {
    taskdef(name:'jrc',classname:'net.sf.jasperreports.ant.
  JRAntCompileTask',classpath:configurations.jasperreports.asPath)`
    sourceSets.main.output.classesDir = new File(buildDir,   "classes/main")
                sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.mkdirs()
    jrc(srcdir: jasperSourceDir, destdir:sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)          {




                    **classpath(path: sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)**  
     //Here i need to add the classes directory of module-B classes--HOW to       add       the module-B classes so the .jrxml can access that and generate the report..                        
                   include(name: '**/*.jrxml')
                }
             }
            }
   dependencies {       
  compile project(':B')
  //provided other dependencies as per build needs.

  }
```

ERROR:-

```
[ant:jrc] File : C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\Project\C\src\main\jasper\Test.jrxml ... FAILED.
[ant:jrc] Error compiling report design : C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\Project\C\src\main\jasper\Test.jrxml
[ant:jrc] net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid :
[ant:jrc]        1. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.B.ClassName
[ant:jrc]       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.verifyDesign(JRAbstractCompiler.java
```

Comment: Hi Dave.. could you suggest me. how to add the   class path of other module..

Comment: There is insufficient information in the question to provide an answer. Show the JRXML code.